# Kernel memcpy actually copied more bytes than the specified length

Tags: crash, kernel, memcpy

I have a kernel crash problem:

> BUG: unable to handle page fault for address: ffff88812c410000 Stack information shows ip_frag_next-->skb_copy_bits-->memcpy_orig+52

The analysis shows that the incoming `memcpy` call was for 620 bytes, but when it crashed, it found that it had already copied 107520 bytes. The result is an access exception.

What would cause this to happen?

```
RDX: current offset
RBX: specified length of memcpy
RAX: dest pointer of memcpy
RDI: current position of dest
    [exception RIP: memcpy_orig+52]
    RIP: ffffffff80a98ed4  RSP: ffffc90000067698  RFLAGS: 00010282
    RAX: ffff88812c3f5c24  RBX: 000000000000026c  RCX: 0000000000001cfc
    RDX: fffffffffffe5e4c  RSI: ffff888002b3014a  RDI: ffff88812c40ffe4
    RBP: ffff88812c3f5c24   R8: 657fc3fb17a4d6f3   R9: 763c3854b6c4e057
    R10: 55cc9b5ed64cab61  R11: 2afd84bbcdd9c7a3  R12: ffffffff814cbbc0
    R13: 000000000000026c  R14: 0000000000001cfc  R15: 0000000000001f68


crash> dis -r memcpy_orig+52
0xffffffff80a98ea0 <memcpy_orig>:       mov    %rdi,%rax
0xffffffff80a98ea3 <memcpy_orig+3>:     cmp    $0x20,%rdx
0xffffffff80a98ea7 <memcpy_orig+7>:     jb     0xffffffff80a98f27 <memcpy_orig+135>
0xffffffff80a98ea9 <memcpy_orig+9>:     cmp    %dil,%sil
0xffffffff80a98eac <memcpy_orig+12>:    jl     0xffffffff80a98ee3 <memcpy_orig+67>
0xffffffff80a98eae <memcpy_orig+14>:    sub    $0x20,%rdx
0xffffffff80a98eb2 <memcpy_orig+18>:    sub    $0x20,%rdx
0xffffffff80a98eb6 <memcpy_orig+22>:    mov    (%rsi),%r8
0xffffffff80a98eb9 <memcpy_orig+25>:    mov    0x8(%rsi),%r9
0xffffffff80a98ebd <memcpy_orig+29>:    mov    0x10(%rsi),%r10
0xffffffff80a98ec1 <memcpy_orig+33>:    mov    0x18(%rsi),%r11
0xffffffff80a98ec5 <memcpy_orig+37>:    lea    0x20(%rsi),%rsi
0xffffffff80a98ec9 <memcpy_orig+41>:    mov    %r8,(%rdi)
0xffffffff80a98ecc <memcpy_orig+44>:    mov    %r9,0x8(%rdi)
0xffffffff80a98ed0 <memcpy_orig+48>:    mov    %r10,0x10(%rdi)
0xffffffff80a98ed4 <memcpy_orig+52>:    mov    %r11,0x18(%rdi)
```

From the code, memcpy should only copy the specified 620 bytes of data. But instead it copies more than 107520 bytes of data, which ultimately leads to an access exception